# How do I make the login screen with the main tabview controller that makes it open the first time the app is opened

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

[Link to image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b9t8.png)
This is the view of the screens

I want

I can't link it to the main tab bar controller

Answer (score 0):

Give the nav controller that parents the login screen a storyboard identifier. Next, create a custom UITabBarController subclass and assign it to the Tab Bar Controller. In its viewDidAppear method, check to see if you need to log in. If so, instantiate the login nav controller via its storyboard ID and present it modally.

Answer (score 0):

Set your login screen as initial view controller. You can set view controller as initial view from attribute inspector. When user login's successfully, present your main tab view controller.